# Regex to filter word with suffix from string

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.6.2

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.6.2 application.

I need to write a regex to filter certain files.

The filename must not include the word "house" as well as the file suffix png, jpg, or gif.

So far I came up with this regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\w*house\w*\b.+.(jpg|png|gif)$");
```

It seems to work fine with the following words:

- zt_housedsaf-34.png
- housedsaf-34.gif

But it doesn't filter these words i.e.:

- house.gif
- 123house.png

Do you know how to write a regex to solve this issue?

Comment: You can add matching a hyphen `\w*house[\w-]*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$` https://regex101.com/r/PZKDHS/1 or change the `.+` to `.*` and escape the dot `\b\w*house\w*\b.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$`

Comment: Sounds more like `if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^(?!.*?\bhouse\b)(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$)") { return true; }` (well, if there is a match, it is a valid string). Or, if these two conditions are AND, `^(?!.*?\b\w*house\w*\b.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern does not match the last 2 strings because `.+` matches 1 or more characters and the `.` after it also matches a character.

So after matching `house` there should be 2 of any characters after it, and then  match any of the alternatives `jpg` `png` `gif`.

Depending on the allowed characters, you could match 0 or more characters followed by escaping the dot to match it literally.

If you don't need to capture the suffix, you can wrap the alternatives in a non capture group:

```
\b\w*house\w*\b.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YenCu/1)

Or you could narrow down the allowed characters matching only word chars and a hyphen and start the pattern matching word chars without a word boundary:

```
\w*house[\w-]*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H4atMl/1)